# Two identical lines of react state are returning different results

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to work out what's going on here (I've been working on https://stackblitz.com/edit/react and am now trying to work locally after setting react up). If you look at this:

```
this.state = {
      reviews: Reviews,
      avgRating: (
        Reviews.reduce((total, cur) => total + cur.rating, 0) / Reviews.length
      ).toFixed(1),
      totalReviews: Reviews.length,
      initialReview: Reviews.find(({ init }) => init === true),
      currentReview: Reviews.find(({ current }) => current === true)
    };
```

The `currentReview` property is defined - but it returns undefined when called later on - for example, in the render method, this correctly returns the reviews information:

```
{console.log(Reviews.find(({ current }) => current === true))}
```

And as above, this is what currentReview equals as defined in the this.state code. However, for some unknown reason, logging the below returns undefined:

```
{console.log(this.state.currentReview)}
```

How can this return undefined but the line above correctly return the data when they should literally be 100% exactly the same! Can someone explain?

For visibility, here's the full index.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";
import ReviewsLeftArea from "./ReviewsLeftArea";
import ReviewsRightArea from "./ReviewsRightArea";
import AllReviews from "./AllReviews";
import Reviews from "./reviews.json";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      reviews: Reviews,
      avgRating: (
        Reviews.reduce((total, cur) => total + cur.rating, 0) / Reviews.length
      ).toFixed(1),
      totalReviews: Reviews.length,
      initialReview: Reviews.find(({ init }) => init === true),
      currentReview: Reviews.find(({ current }) => current === true)
    };
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    this.prev = this.prev.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.state.reviews.forEach(function(review) {
      if (review.init) {
        review["current"] = true;
      } else {
        review["current"] = false;
      }
    });
  }

  updateReview = (bool, obj, i) => {
    const newState = [...this.state.reviews];
    newState[i].current = bool;

    this.setState({
      currentReview: obj,
      reviews: newState
    });
  };

  next() {
    const revState = this.state.reviews,
      updateCurrentStatus = obj => {
        revState.forEach((rev, i) => {
          if (obj === rev) {
            this.updateReview(true, obj, i);
          } else {
            this.updateReview(false, obj, i);
          }
        });
      };

    for (let i = 0; i < revState.length; i++) {
      if (
        revState[i]["current"] &&
        i < revState.length - 1
      ) {
        updateCurrentStatus(revState[i + 1]);
        break;
      } else if (revState[i]["current"]) {
        updateCurrentStatus(revState[0]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  prev() {
    const revState = this.state.reviews,
      updateCurrentStatus = obj => {
        revState.forEach((rev, i) => {
          if (obj === rev) {
            this.updateReview(true, obj, i);
          } else {
            this.updateReview(false, obj, i);
          }
        });
      };

    for (let i = 0; i < revState.length; i++) {
      if (revState[i]["current"] && i !== 0) {
        updateCurrentStatus(revState[i - 1]);
        break;
      } else if (revState[i]["current"]) {
        updateCurrentStatus(revState[revState.length - 1]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="reviews-area-wrap">
        <div id="reviews-area-inner">
          <ReviewsLeftArea
            totalReviews={this.state.totalReviews}
            avgRating={this.state.avgRating}
          />
          {console.log(Reviews.find(({ current }) => current === true))}
          {console.log(this.state.currentReview)}
        />
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And here's the reviews json file:

```
[
    {
      "name": "Joe Bloggs",
      "comment": "I liked it. Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
      "rating": 4,
      "date": "22 April 2020",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Nick Smith",
      "comment": "Great, thanks.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Mary Manson",
      "comment": "Amazing - consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus.",
      "rating": 5,
      "date": "07 March 2020",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Rachel Stevens",
      "comment": "Pretty good. Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Jack Hawthorn",
      "comment": "Aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      "rating": 4,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Jacob Haywood",
      "comment": "Awful. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      "rating": 1,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Ben Stiller",
      "comment": "Thanks a lot.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Xiao Wei",
      "comment": "Great, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "John Harwood",
      "comment": "Rubbish - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 2,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Jackie Chan",
      "comment": "Not great - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 2.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Chuck Norris",
      "comment": "A poor 1.5 - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 1.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": true,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Duncan Jones",
      "comment": "Satisfactory. Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 3,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Peter Lahm",
      "comment": "Was ok. Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 3.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Simon Arnold",
      "comment": "Nice - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 4,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Claire Pullen",
      "comment": "Great - quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.",
      "rating": 4.5,
      "date": "29 December 2019",
      "init": false,
      "current": null
    }
  ]
```

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: When (and under what circumstances) are they not equal? There aren't **any** truthy `current` values in the Reviews.json file, so `Reviews.find(({ current }) => current === true)` will always return `undefined`. I imagine they *are* equal on the first and subsequent renders until `next` or `prev` are invoked and `this.state. currentReview` is set to some review object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here has to do with the order in which React lifecycle methods are called. The `constructor` method is called first, then `componentWillMount`, then `render`. So in `constructor`, `componentWillMount` has not yet been run, thus the elements of `Reviews` have not had their `current` attribute set yet, and none has `current === true`. The reason your first `console.log` call in `render` finds the correct review is because `render` runs after `componentWillMount`.

To fix this, I'd recommend getting rid of your `componentWillMount` method entirely and moving its logic into `constructor`. `componentWillMount` is getting its name changed to `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` in the next version of React, indicating that the React team does not recommend using this method. Additionally the body of your `componentWillMount` method directly modifies state rather than using `setState`, which [should not be done](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) in React.

Here is an updated version of `constructor` that will work as desired:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      const reviews = Reviews.map(review => ({...review, current: review.init}));

      this.state = {
        reviews: reviews,
        avgRating: (
          reviews.reduce((total, cur) => total + cur.rating, 0) / reviews.length
        ).toFixed(1),
        totalReviews: reviews.length,
        initialReview: reviews.find(({ init }) => init === true),
        currentReview: reviews.find(({ current }) => current === true),
      };
      this.next = this.next.bind(this);
      this.prev = this.prev.bind(this);
    }

    // rest of component (without `componentWillUpdate`)...
}
```

Additionally, your `updateReview` method looks like it might run into issues as it is called multiple times within a loop and [state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), so the last call may be the only one that takes hold. (Also this method directly modifies state even though it also calls `setState` and the direct modification is why it may be working properly at the moment).

To fix this issue, you can use the callback version of `setState`, which accepts a callback function whose argument is the current version of state (making it able to handle asynchronous state updates).

For example:

```js
updateReview = (bool, obj, i) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        currentReview: obj,
        reviews: prevState.reviews.map((e, j) => j === i ? {...e, current: bool} : e),
    }));
}
```